# How to merely stop child actors upon a parent's restart?

Tags: scala, akka, scala-2.10, akka-persistence

I have an Akka parent actor with several children. When the parent actor is restarted, I need it to simply stop its children, rather than stopping and re-creating or restarting them. (A child would be created manually later, if it's needed.) Is there a way to do this? Perhaps by overriding the parent's `preRestart` method in some way?

Comment: how do you create children: unconditionally during parent initialization or on receive?

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov On receive.

Comment: It looks like children created on receive (rather than during parent initialization) are stopped but not re-created. However, I haven't convinced myself of this. Can anyone confirm that this is the actual behavior?

Comment: yes, that's what `preRestart` does - see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `Actor` disposes of it's children on restart. Here is the `Actor.preRestart` code:

```
  /**
   * User overridable callback: '''By default it disposes of all children and then calls `postStop()`.'''
   * @param reason the Throwable that caused the restart to happen
   * @param message optionally the current message the actor processed when failing, if applicable
   * <p/>
   * Is called on a crashed Actor right BEFORE it is restarted to allow clean
   * up of resources before Actor is terminated.
   */
  @throws(classOf[Exception]) // when changing this you MUST also change UntypedActorDocTest
  //#lifecycle-hooks
  def preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any]): Unit = {
    context.children foreach { child ⇒
      context.unwatch(child)
      context.stop(child)
    }
    postStop()
  }
```

As you can see parent will stop and unwatch its children.
You can override it like this to make an actor keep it's children alive:

```
override def preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any]): Unit = ()
```

So for your purposes you don't need to override `preRestart` and you'll get desired behavior. You can look at other callbacks if you want to have more custom behavior like starting children on start but not on restart event.